# How to route specific destination using specific interface

Tags: linux, routing, source-routing

On my server i have two interfaces; one is eth0, other is bond0.

Unfortunately eth0 is only 100 mbits, opposed to bond0 which is 1000 mbits.

```
eth0 is 10.0.0.21 gw 10.0.0.1
bond0 is 10.0.0.22 gw 10.0.0.1
```

I have to reach another host on public wan like 12.34.56.76 but using bond0 only.

Can I do this with ip route ? Or is it just for subnet routing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be as simple as

```
route add -host 12.34.56.76 gw 10.0.0.1 dev bond0
```

Comment: wow, that was so ... simple :) Thx !